# Total execute time in thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, httprequest

Here's my code:

```
foreach (var obj in listObj)        
{
    Thread t = new Thread(()=> dosomething(obj))

    t.IsBackground = true;
    t.Start();

    Thread.Sleep(5);
}
```

The `listObj` has 500 `obj`, the `dosomething` function may take 100 milliseconds and the total time for ending the loop is 9 seconds. I don't know why it take 9s. Please help.

Inside the `dosomething` a url is called using `httprequest`.

Comment: Can you show us a summary of your dosomething?

Comment: Are you looking for profiling tools to find how long these 500 threads takes and locked for resources or in context switch etc ?

for e.g. in you scenario you have httpRequest, and thr is a limit on number of ports you can open , so other request would need to wait till the resource is disposed. Also lot depends on the h/w you are running on ..Please do more specific on the question .. thanks

Comment: The `Thread.Sleep` command executes in foreground, so you loose here 2.5 s.

Comment: Is there any particular reason for `Thread.Sleep(5);`?

Comment: `may take 100 millisecond` - how do you know that?

Comment: This loop takes at least 7.8 seconds.  Thread.Sleep() has *many* evils, especially when used in threaded code.  Add another one, it won't sleep for 5 milliseconds, you'll get 500 x 15.6 msec.  Delete that, fix the real problem.

Comment: Thank for your help. I remove the Thread.sleep(5) and it still take 9s. maybe it depend on Dosomething function. I have explain my issue as below comment. can you take a look on it. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a simple test program for that:

```
    void DoSomething()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }

    void Test()
    {
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        for (int i=0; i<500; i++)        
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(() => DoSomething());

            t.IsBackground = true;
            t.Start();

            Thread.Sleep(5);
        }
        MessageBox.Show(DateTime.Now.Subtract(dt).TotalSeconds.ToString() );
     }
```

This takes on my slow old PC about 2.8 sec.
When I comment all `Thread.Sleep` calls I get cca 2 seconds.
The limits of maximum numer of threads for 1 process are relatively high, so this is not a problem. 
When you want to have detailed info about what is going on, you can use Sysinternals [Process monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/cs-cz/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx). There you will see what is going on. Maybe some libraries are loading or something like that.

[image: Process monitor]

Comment: Personally, I prefer the [`Stopwatch` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) instead of subtracting `DateTime` instances.

Comment: Thank you very much. it's take 2.9s on my PC. May I explain my issue and you can help me if possible. I need to get data from more then different 500 Urls with the minimum time possible like 1s. each request take about 100s. do you have any solution?

Answer (score -2):

It should roughly be 500*5/1000 = 2.5 secs + overhead(for other statements in for loop)
There's no way it'll be taking 9s. Recheck your debug statements used to calculate time duration

Comment: Please mark that the threads are executing paralel.

Comment: sorry .. 500*5/100 = 2.5 secs !!!!